# Can't import discord.js typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import, discord.js

I'm rewriting a Discord Bot from JS to TS, but I'm facing an issue.

Writing this doesn't work

```js
import { Message } from 'discord.js';
```

but this does

```js
const { Message } = require('discord.js');
```

What can be the reason for such a behavior?

The error is as shown
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you show your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: Have you installed the discord.js package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you when targeting `es2015` or later under "module" in tsconfig.json then the error occurs because -

- `moduleResolution` is calculated/set as `classic` in tsconfig.json
- and if `paths` aren't specified for the modules in tsconfig.json

To resolve the error

- set the "module" in tsconfig.json to `commonjs`
- change the `moduleResolution = node` or
- add the library path in `paths` section in `tsconfig.json`, see the below documentation for the same.

See the [`complete guide`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) how typescript resolves the module for both *relative and non-relative* types of modules in typescript.

Comment: Thanks you, I spent too much time for a such simple things !